# Reloading a MacBook with applications

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, ssd

My daughter has a MacBook, 10.6.8 and we have the install discs. 
It's gotten to that age, 5-6 years, where it runs sluggishly, and I'm thinking to wipe the drive, maybe replace with an SSD, and reinstall the OS.

I am looking to be sure that the applications that have been activated by serial number continue to work. Is there a simple process to do this? In the very old Mac days, the serial number / keys were stored in a preference folder. Now, I'm not so sure what pieces need to be saved to move software from an old drive to new.

I'd go the CCC (clone) route, but a full image would probably take the sluggishness with it. Trying to clean up the next version of the drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a single Time Machine backup, just in case.

When you wipe the laptop, use the Time Machine drive to selectively (manually) restore certain items.  Information and files related to application licensing will most often be located in:

~/Library/
~/Library/Application Support
~/Library/Preferences

Answer (score 1):

the sluggishness may come from newer O/S upgrades that have degraded the performance of the computer. I say this because Mac O/S rarely has the "bitrot" issues that plague Windows, making it necessary (if not just advisable) to reinstall the O/S every 3-4 years. So if you have kept up with the O/S upgrades that may actually be the culprit.

There are also utilities that will clean up temp files, caches and run the maintenance scripts that can slow down the system. I personally like [Onyx](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/11582/onyx) (MacUpdate.com). Run that, go to the automation tab and run it with the defaults. Reboot when done. Initially things will be a little slower (MS apps need to rebuild their font cache) but after an hour or so of use you should be able to tell if cruft has built up in the corners that was fixed by Onyx.

Failing that I would go with a replacement drive, an SSD would be best. An SSD will make the system feel a lot faster. And for those folks with some mechanical ability it's a quick and easy do it yourself repair. ifixit.com has instructions and I have used the SSD kits from OWC several times with good effect. they come with an external USB drive case, so you clone your old drive to the new one in the USB case then swap the drives. Pretty simple if a bit time consuming (count on half a day for backup and hardware swap. More if you are less experienced, less if you've done this kind of thing before.)

And depending on how much RAM you currently have, more can help too. I like 8GB for general use, more if it is affordable. Many people swear by 4GB being enough but I have found that for my purposes 8GB is the sweet spot.